# Ionic app post fails with "Referer checking failed - no Referer."

Tags: django, angular, ionic-framework

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins):
`Django’s CSRF protection requires that the request have a Referer header that matches the origin present in the Host header.`

Using Ionic 3.9.2 (Angular 5.2.10), how does one satisfy this requirement when posting forms since one can't add the referer header? Disabling csrf protection is not an option. The same URL works via browser (even Ionic's in-app browser but the experience is just not desirable). I'm posting JSON data.

My code:

```
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN': csrftoken});
return this.http.post(
  hostUrl + "/auth/reset_password?org=" + org, body, {headers: headers}
  ).toPromise();
```